# trimming sequences from both ends of a fasta file

Tags: biopython

I have a fasta file which looks like (original_reads.fasta)

> read_identifier:abcdefgh
>   AAGTGTAAAGCCTGGGGTGCCTAATGATCGATCGATCAGGTGTGTGAGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGAATGGGAGTCCTGCAGCGCACTGTGCCCGACTGAAATTCCGTATCAGAATCTGTTGACTTTCTCCCAGATCGATCGATCAAAAAGGATCTCAAGAAGATCC

My library sequence starts after the first 37 bp (which is an adaptor sequence) and is 96 bp long. The remaining 34 base pairs after that is another adaptor sequence. I want to trim the 37 bp adaptor and the 34 bp adaptor. The code I tried does not work since the whole sequence is trimmed in the second round. I used biopython. Here is my code: please suggest solutions.

```
def trim_adaptors(records, adaptor):

    """Trims perfect adaptor sequences.

    This is a generator function, the records argument should
    be a list or iterator returning SeqRecord objects.
    """
    len_adaptor = len(adaptor) #cache this for later
    for record in records:
        index = record.seq.find(adaptor)
        if index == -1:
            #adaptor not found, so won't trim
            yield record
        else:
            #trim off the adaptor
            yield record[index+len_adaptor:]



original_reads = SeqIO.parse("original_reads.fasta","fasta")

trimmed_reads1 = trim_adaptors(original_reads,"AAGTGTAAAGCCTGGGGTGCCTAATGATCGATCGATC")

count = SeqIO.write(trimmed_reads1,"trimmed1.fasta","fasta")

print("Saved %i reads" %count)

trimmed_reads1 = SeqIO.parse("trimmed1.fasta","fasta")

trimmed_reads2 = trim_adaptors(trimmed_reads1,"GATCGATCGATCAAAAAGGATCTCAAGAAGATCC")

count = SeqIO.write(trimmed_reads2,"trimmed.fasta","fasta")

print("Saved %i reads" %count)
```

Comment: I found the solution: create one more trim_adaptors function and modify the final line to yeild record[:index]

Answer (score 0):

create one more trim_adaptors function and modify the final line to yeild record[:index]